# Select Random Numbers from a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my query.

```
SELECT TOP 2 NUM 
FROM QT_PIVOT
WHERE NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 45 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

I'm selecting 2 random numbers from a list but I don't want that these numbers to be continuous

Sometimes the result is

```
NUM
----
2
3
```

And I don't want this

Thanks , and sorry for my English u.u

Comment: What's the point of picking numbers at random then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the same as the 2nd approach Gordon uses except it lacks the use of the lag function and therefor will work on SQL-2008.

```
WITH Data AS(
    SELECT *, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID())
    FROM sys.objects AS O
),
r AS(
    SELECT TOP 1 *, SkipRow = 0
    FROM Data
    WHERE Data.RowNum = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.*, SkipRow = CASE WHEN d.object_id BETWEEN r.object_id -2 AND r.object_id + 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    FROM r
        JOIN Data AS D
            ON r.RowNum + 1 = D.RowNum
)
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM R
WHERE R.SkipRow = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to select the first number, and then select an appropriate second number:

```
WITH r AS (
      SELECT TOP 1 num
      FROM QT_PIVOT
      WHERE NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 45
      ORDER BY NEWId()
     )
select num
from r
union all
select top 1 q.num
from qt_pivot q join
     r
     on q.num not in (r.num, r.num - 1, r.num + 1)
where q.num between 1 and 45 
order by newid();
```

Another approach (if you had SQL Server 2012+) would use `lag()` to remove any possibilities that do not meet the conditions:

```
WITH r AS (
      SELECT num, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      FROM QT_PIVOT
      WHERE NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 45
     )
SELECT r.num
FROM (SELECT r.*, LAG(num) OVER (ORDER BY seqnum) as prevnum
      FROM r
     ) r
WHERE prevnum is null or
      prevnum not in (num - 1, num + 1);
```

EDIT:

The first approach doesn't work, because SQL Server *always* re-evaluates CTEs, and there is not even a hint to fix this problem.  Here is an alternative approach, that will ensure that values are not consecutive:

```
WITH r as (
      SELECT (1 + checksum(newid()) * 45) as r1,
             (2 + checksum(newid()) * 43) as r2
     )
SELECT q.num
FROM QT_PIVOT q
WHERE q.num = r.r1 or
      q.num = 1 + (r.r1 + r.r2) % 45;
```

This calculates a two random numbers.  The first is a random position.  The second is an allowable offset (hence the "2" and "43") to guarantee that the numbers are not adjacent.

Comment: There is a `)` missing in the `over` clause of the second query.

Comment: The CTE in the first approach gives a different row each time it's used (before and after `the union all`) and therefore give false result.

Comment: @MWillemse . . . Thank you, thank you.  After suffering through understand why `CHOOSE()` fails in a similar circumstances, this should be embedded in my knowledge.  Most databases will materialize a CTE either always or under reasonable circumstances.